# TypeError: Object( ) is not a function when using browser router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner at javascript and React. I started to work on that project  https://github.com/udacity/reactnd-project-myreads-starter, when I write this in the index file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I get this error

[image]

The dependencies I have for that project

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```

I don't know whats causing this. I didn't do anything to the code except adding browser router and it was running fine when I cloned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-router-dom is hook based under the hood, but hooks weren't introduced until React v16.8.4. You are still using React v16.6.3. Update to a newer version of React (`react`) and ReactDom (`react-dom`).